# Angular2 performance with lots of input elements with two way binding

Tags: performance, angular

I have a component which displays a  UI similar to a spreadsheet. There are lots of  elements with two way binding [(ngModel)] to a mutable Object.

As soon as the number of inputs grows past 100 or so inputs the UI becomes sluggish. The profiler shows a lot of time in Decimal format (decimal pipe).

I can think of a couple of possible solutions:

1. Using immutable objects somehow?
2. Customising the 2 way databinding?

I am *not* using ChangeDetectionStrategy OnPush, but I am curious as to how this will help and how to actually implement it with [(ngModel)] on html inputs.

Comment: Are you using `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`?

Comment: No, I am not using ChangeDetectionStrategy OnPush

Comment: That's the first measure for better performance for mor fine-grained control aboit how much work change detection should do.

Comment: Try to use OnPush for your ChangeDetectionStrategy as @GünterZöchbauer said and you could try to do a virtual-scroll to avoid the need of more inputs.

Comment: Why not to use FormGroup?

Comment: How do you use OnPush for two way databinding [(ngModel)] on inputs?

Comment: With `OnPush` you don't have to change binding. What you need to do is notify Angular when it should run change detection like injecting `ChangeDetectorRef` and call its `detectChanges()`. This way you avoid redundant change detection cycles that might slow your app down. Can you provide a Plunker that allows to reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many input fields on a page is stressful both for the CPU and the user.

Instead of showing a spreadsheet with many input fields simultaneously - I would rather make the cell an input field only when focused, and otherwise only show the value of the cell. Use *ngIf on the input checking for the current cell being edited.

This way you should be able to keep the functionality you want, but by making only the focused spreadsheet cell an input - that should improve the performance of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Since `NgModel` is directive it does not support change detection strategies, it means that you should avoid `NgModel`. The only way is to create custom component that uses `OnPush` strategy and wraps input field.